# How to script ElasticBeanstalk deployment for ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My app has outgrown using Visual Studio to deploy it, I need to script it out so it's more reliable and more hands-off.

Does anyone have any links to resources or perhaps a script I could modify for my stuff available?

I've not been able to find in the AWS documentation scripting for deploying apps to ELB.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend giving [AWS CLI](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) a try. Documentation on how to use it with elasticbeanstalk is available [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/index.html).